# add horizontal scrollView to vertical scroll uicollectionView

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, horizontal-scrolling

I have vertical scroll UICollectionView with many sections. I need to make one of sections scroll horizontal.  Can I implement it by set the UICollectionView? or I have to nest a UICollection(SCrollVIew) to the main UICollectionView. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to nest the collection views. You'll need to put a horizontally-scrolling collection view in a cell in the vertically-scrolling collection view. iOS supports this arrangement.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your reply.